# C++ Bring window to foreground after killing LogonUI.exe

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7

At first I thought that the program which launched the command to kill LogonUI.exe was closed right before LogonUI.exe was reexecuted by itself.

However, I found out that this wasn't right at all as in fact the program is not closed but it seems to me that it's moved to the background (I figured out that the program is still running thanks to Tasklist)

Here's some code which tries to show this problem (is to be run on the log on screen)

If anyone could solve this it would be fantastic. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


void Menu(char &sel_menu);
void KillLogonUI();
void Tasklist();

void Menu(char &sel_menu)
{
    cout << "Type 1 to kill LogonUI.exe" << endl;
    cout << "Type 2 to list running processes" << endl;
    cout << endl << "Type 0 to exit" << endl;
    cout << endl << endl << ">> "; cin >> sel_menu;
}

void KillLogonUI()
{
    HWND hWnd =  GetForegroundWindow();

    system("Taskkill /F /IM LogonUI.exe");
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
}

void Tasklist()
{
    system("Tasklist");
}

int main()
{
    char sel_menu;

    do
    {
        Menu(sel_menu);

        switch (sel_menu)
        {
            case '1': KillLogonUI(); break;
            case '2': Tasklist(); break;

            default:
                if (sel_menu != '0')
                    {
                        cout << endl << "Wrong input";
                        Sleep(1000);
                    }
        }
    } while(sel_menu != '0');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"If anyone could solve this"* - You haven't explained, what *"this"* is.

Comment: This one time i killed logonui and it had logged me out and made me think that my user profile was deleted. because my username wasn't there at the login screen. I restarted my computer and was relieved to see my user profile... not helpful but just something that happened to me once.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want to achive? Run application at logon? It can be done next way:
1. Create system service (not user level service)
2. When service run - run your application in winlogon session `"WinSta0\Winlogon"`, here the article how to run your application in different session with correct security token: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite#_articleTop 
3. Set your application property "topmost".
4. When service close - close your application.
This logic will work with all windows from 7 to windows 10, server 12,16 - I'm tested in all and it works.

Killing LogonIU is bad idea. If you need hide it - just hide it window and/or run you program in fullscreen.